# How to move artifacts between two nexus repositories (jenkins)?

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, nexus

We use Jenkins + Gradle Script build.
To uploading artifacts to nexus we use:

```
uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                def auth = { authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword) }
                repository(url: rpmReleasesRepoUrl, auth)
                pom.groupId = project.group
                pom.version = project.version
                pom.artifactId = project.product
            }
        }
    }
```

We need a job, that takes artifacts from one nexus and uploads it to another nexus.

Can you advice what will be the better way to do this and if there is any useful articles/examples (seeing gradle/maven/nexus for first time)?

Comment: Why not publish twice? once to each nexus?

Comment: Release must be tested before we can send it to client

Comment: is the test a manual step?

Comment: There is a jenkisn plugin for use with the free version of nexus that allows you to promote binaries between nexus instances: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactPromotionPlugin

Comment: yeap, test team responsible for testing. Thanks, will check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Jenkins artifact promotion plugin

This is a non-gradle solution, but you can use [this jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactPromotionPlugin) in your jenkins workflow to promote your build binaries from one nexus repo to another.

#### 2. Use commandline parameter to provide repo URL for publishing

```
uploadArchives {
    ...
            repository(url: project.getProperty('repoURL'), auth)
    ...
}
```

then run `gradle uploadArchives -PrepoURL=http://nexusurl` using a different nexus url as needed.

#### 3. Use a different task to publish to each repo

```
ext.repoURL=''

task publishToRepo1()<<{
    repoURL = 'http://nexus1.url'
    configureRepo(repoURL)
}
publishToRepo1.finalizedBy('uploadArchives')

task publishToRepo2()<<{
    repoURL = 'http://nexus2.url'
    configureRepo(repoURL)
}
publishToRepo2.finalizedBy('uploadArchives')

def configureRepo(url){
    uploadArchives.repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            def auth = { authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword) }
            repository(url: url, auth)
            pom.groupId = project.group
            pom.version = project.version
            pom.artifactId = project.name
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    doFirst{
        if (!repoURL){
            println "Please use publishToRepo1 or publishToRepo1 to publish"
            throw new GradleException('use of uploadArchives is restricted!')
        }
    }
}
```

This would cause gradle build to fail if `uploadArchives` is called directly with a message to use publishToRepo1 or publishToRepo2 instead. Calling those tasks directly will call uploadArchives with the appropriate repo url configured.

Comment: This does not do what the user asked. It shows how to upload to two repos but leaves out how to retrieve from one repo and upload to a second one.